# bootstrap modal dynamic data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I want open model and get model content dynamic but when i call ajax file and get response data then model not open and i cant access json response data in php code . When I put my model in ajx file and get html response then response success but  model can't open.please help me to fix issue.

```
<script>
    function test(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Appointment/get_model",
            data: "id=" + id,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {

                $("#model_test").html(data);
                $("#myModal2").modal('show');
                //displayRecords();
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

This one is my ajax file `get_model.php`:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id     = $_GET['id'];
    $query  = $this->db->query("select * from appointment where id='" . $id . "'");
    $result = $query->row();
    print_r($result);
    die;
    //echo(json_encode($result));
}
?>
   <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group  col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                            <label for="usr">Doctor Name:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group  col-lg-7 col-md-7 ">
                            <input type="name" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" id="email_id" value="<?php
$result->name;
?>" placeholder="Doctor Name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group  col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                            <label for="usr">Contact No:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group  col-lg-7 col-md-7 ">
                            <input type="name" value="<?php
$result->contact_no;
?>" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" id="email_id" placeholder="Patient Name" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And this one is my html code  i want to open model here with dynamic content:

```
<div id="model_test">
</div>


   <?php



                            foreach($result as $row)

                            {
<td onclick="test(<?php echo $row->id;?>)" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $row->id;?>" data-target="#myModal2" ><?php echo ucfirst($row->name);?></td>
}
```

Comment: Please format the code to make it more readable and remove non-code parts from code snippets

Comment: Please clear your question..@pinal

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem in the div closing tags, kindly check that all div  tags are closed properly, try the below code

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">

  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group  col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                            <label for="usr">Doctor Name:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group  col-lg-7 col-md-7 ">
                            <input type="name" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" id="email_id" value="<?php $result->name; ?>"
                            placeholder="Doctor Name" required >
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group  col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                            <label for="usr">Contact No:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group  col-lg-7 col-md-7 ">
                            <input type="name" value="<?php $result->contact_no; ?>" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" id="email_id"  
                            placeholder="Patient Name" required >
                            </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  and this one is my html code  i want to open model here with dynamic content

  <div id="model_test">
   </div>
  </div>
```

```
<td onclick="test(<?php echo $row->id;?>)" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $row->id;?>" data-target="#myModal2" ><?php echo ucfirst($row->name);?></td>
```

Comment: can you post complete HTML code? for the display page?

Comment: now i open my modal but  modal is override.  i explain in question pls  help me

Comment: you have to provide us with a complete description, I want to help you, but at least execute the code, select view source from your browser, then past the result in the question area, then tell us again using that code as example, what exactly need to be done.

Comment: if you want to show only model_test, then delete everything between `<div class="modal-body">` and its closing div, after that, put your div `<div id="model_test">` inside `<div class="modal-body">`

Comment: no i want modal content also and  now i solve my model open issue but problem is here when i click first time on <td> (given in my code) then modal open proper and it's work perfect but when i click second td then model override i mean two modal open and i can't perform any action.

Comment: I see, you want when you click the modal second time, it will open and the old one disappear?!

Comment: add this line at the beginning of your test function: `$('#myModal2').data('bs.modal', null);`

Comment: yes, when i click on any another td i mean second ya third  row <td> then first one is close and open another but i can't because when i click on second time then both open  first and also second.

Comment: which one line...?

Comment: before: `$.ajax({`

Comment: still same issue.

Comment: use this code `$("a[data-target=#myModal2]").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");

    // load the url and show modal on success
    $("#myModal2 .modal-body").load(target, function() { 
         $("#myModal2").modal("show"); 
    });
});` don't forget to add a new attribute called `href` to your `td`

Answer (score 0):

You did not use MVC programming pattern!
You use database code into a view?!
Please make a Controller with the function:

```
function get_model(){
 $this->load->model('get_model');
 $value = $this->get_model->your_db_data_retrieve_model_function(data);
 $data = json_encode($value);
    $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output($data); 
 }
```

also a model (retrieve data from database) is needed:

```
function retrieve_data($id) {
  . ....
  return $data;
}
```

remember to use a controller to get the data from $_GET using

```
$this->input->get('your_variable_name')
```

passing it to model (the ID).

Consider to read the principle of MVC (model-view-controller) pattern.